# How to Properly Setup Generic ArrayLists in Java (based on SkipLists)

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm *trying* to code up SkipLists as I just learned about the data structure.

**Main Question:** How do I properly setup a Generic ArrayList for SkipLists?

So far, I've learned java does not like generic arrays for example:

```
SkippyList.java:138: error: generic array creation
                SkipNode<T>[] criticalPoints = (SkipNode<T>[]) new SkipNode<T>[height];
```

So now I'm trying to use ArrayLists to hold these generic types. I've been scouring the internet and haven't been able to find a solution that works.
I've tried setting up the ArrayList (as a global variable) like `ArrayList<SkipNode<AnyType>>[] next;`

Then in a function such as this one declare it like such:

```
    // Constructor for a node with data, but not wired in.
    public SkipNode(AnyType data, int height)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.height = height;
        this.next = new ArrayList<SkipNode<AnyType>>[height];
        for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
            this.next[i] = null;
    }
```

But then I end up with another error such as this one:

```
SkippyList.java:14: error: generic array creation
                this.next = new ArrayList<SkipNode<AnyType>>[height];
```

For reference the (not updated) constructor for (some) of the nodes:

```
    // Constructor for the head node
    public SkipNode(int height)
    {
        this.data = null;
        this.next = (SkipNode<AnyType>[]) new SkipNode[height];
        for (int i = 0; i <= height; i++)
            this.next[i] = null;
    }
```

I know it is possible, do I need to include the `<AnyType>` (because I've tried to leave it off and still recieve the same result) or am I just improperly creating a Generic ArrayList?

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong brackets :-)

You are trying to create an array "ArrayList[arraySize]" instead of an instance of ArrayList with an initial size

```
new ArrayList<SkipNode<AnyType>>[arraySize];
```

I think what you are trying to do is

```
new ArrayList<SkipNode<AnyType>>(someInitialListSize);
```

But without knowing exactly what type "this.next" is (maybe it really is  SkipNode[]?), it is hard to be sure.